# Recover AadObjectId and/or UserPrincipalName with PnP PowerShelll

Tags: sharepoint-server, pnp-powershell

I am unable to find a way to recover the user principal name from a user object (`Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.User`) with PnP PowerShell.

I would expect with this code (connection is done before of course), to recover the property, since it is not loaded by `Get-PnPUser`.

```
$me = Get-PnPUser -Identity 40939
Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $me -Property AadObjectId
Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $me -Property UserPrincipalName
```

Unfortunately this very simple code is running in this issue. Any property that is not loaded by `Get-PnPUser` cannot be loaded with `Get-PnPProperty`. Yet the properties exist if you check the user object in debug.

```
Get-PnPProperty : Field or property "AadObjectId" does not exist.
At \\nrb1215wi\scripts\Test.ps1:16 char:1
+ Get-PnPProperty $me AadObjectId
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-PnPProperty], ServerException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.EnsureProperty
```

I did not found any solution with CSOM, `$context.Load()` is not accepting any arguments.

Comment: It should be `Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $me -Property AadObjectId`

Comment: I edited the question since it's the recommended way to call commands in PowerShell. Unfortunately, the parameters are correctly passed to the command so this is not the issue.

Comment: Strange, i tested your code and it works. Any chance you could be using an older version of PnP PowerShell ? Maybe try upgrading to the latest one and check ?

Comment: I have the latest release (April), if i try to do that on the Online SharePoint there is no issues, I know that I am using the PnP PowerShell Online version. So if I want to do that on an On Prem Sharepoint I suppose the 2019 version would work. But I don't know the exact impact of using the Online version on On Prem site, this is the first time that I had issues with that.

Comment: There wouldn't be an AadObjectId on-prem, so that makes sense...